# Angular 2: When the url is written (in location bar) the corresponding link is not shown as active

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a few li with a button inside of each one (I have tried with a(nchor) instead buttons) and each button has the routerLinkActive directive, when I click one, the corresponding class (of the directive) is added but if I write the url in the location/address bar the class of the roterLinkActive isn't added to the button

The route works as expected.

This is the template

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <button routerLink="/link1"
                routerLinkActive="active"></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button routerLink="/link2"
                routerLinkActive="active"></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button routerLink="/link3"
                routerLinkActive="active"></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, if I click the first button the address bar shows
`domain.com/link1`
and the button has the class `active`

But if I write `domain.com/link1` and hit enter (or go to that address) the class `active` isn't added to the button, but the component specified in the routes is loaded as expected

I'm using

> `"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2"`
>
> `"@angular/router": "^3.4.0"`

I don't know how to reproduce it in Plunker because when I change the address in the location bar (the last part of router link) seems like I if had requested another plunker

Thanks and sorry I'm new in angular2

Comment: do you have a class called active in your app styles?

Comment: @Aravind In fact is more complex but for simplicity I put active class

Answer (score 0):

You should be using routerLinkActiveOptions

```
<ul routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
    <li>
        <button routerLink="/link1"></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button routerLink="/link2"></button>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button routerLink="/link3></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The routerLinkActive should not be in each button? Plus the routerLinkActiveOptions with the exact true option is for match exactly the router link